# Distinguish between types using SFINAE and void_t

Tags: c++, c++14

I faced some situation where I have to write two functions, one of them should be invoked with primitive types and `std::string`. The other one should be called with other types.

So far I ended with working solution:

```
template <typename...>
struct Void_t_helper {
    using type = void;
};

template <typename... Ts>
using Void_t = typename Void_t_helper<Ts...>::type;


template <typename T, typename = void>
struct Is_string : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> 
struct Is_string<T, Void_t<decltype (std::declval<T> ().c_str ())>> : std::is_same<decltype (std::declval<T> ().c_str ()), const char*>::type {};


template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<Is_string<T>::value || std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void> foo (T) {
    std::cout << "string or primitive\n";
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!Is_string<T>::value && !std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void> foo (T) {
    std::cout << "other type\n";
}
```

And the usage:

```
foo (1);
foo (1.2);
foo (std::string {"fsdf"});
foo (std::vector<int> {1, 2, 3});
foo (std::vector<std::string> {"a", "v", "c"});
```

produces as expected:

```
string or primitive
string or primitive
string or primitive
other type
other type
```

My question is: **Do you know better solution to this kind of problem?**

I am not really sure if checking if `c_str()` exists is the better option I can get. I am aware that I could probably write some wrapper class that for primitive types and `std::string` would have some `category_t` defined with value `X`, and for other types value `Y` and distinguish between these groups using this category, but still I think that `c_str()` checking is more convenient.

Comment: The question is a bit subjective for my tastes, but are you already familiar with [the detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)? And/or Boost.Hana's [`is_valid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1type.html#a2d2e7e08e284f7e0bd1bd9c3ad0e0a2b)?

Comment: @ildjarn I only heard about hana, but don't know it

Comment: "Better" in what respect? Are you asking if there is a better implementation of some `Is_string` trait? Or whether there is a better overall tactic than using some `Is_string` trait in the first place?

Comment: @ildjarn sorry for not to mention the idea. I used `c_str()` because `std::string` has it and `std::vector` has not. I think that even though in this example it is fine, `c_str()` should not be used to distinguish between `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am not really sure if checking if c_str() exists is the better option I can get.

Ideally you'll be checking for what you actually want.

That can either be a set of known types or templates, or it can be a *concept*.

At the moment, you're checking for "the concept of having a c_str() member function which returns a pointer to constant chars".

The question is, what concept does your SFINAE'd function need?

If it will use the `c_str()` member, that's reasonable. But if it's going to use other members or types of the string, you probably want to build a compound concept to describe the parts of the interface you're going to exercise.

Of course, you may just want to confirm that it is actually a specialisation of `std::string`. It's difficult (impossible) to tell unless you state the use case.

Comment: In fact `c_str()` was chosen because it is something that is a part of `std::string`, but not part of `std::vector`. I didn't mention that in the question and also that's why I asked if there is a better option.

Comment: @ArturPyszczuk yes I see. string is almost 'vector-like' except that printing it like you would a vector, element by element makes no sense. When I have built overloaded emitter functions like this in the past I have delegated to partially specialised outputter functors rather than rely on overload selection.